# Unable to boot into Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

So, I had bought a new laptop which came preinstalled with Ubuntu 14.04 but I later installed Windows 10 after removing Ubuntu, I backed up laptop vendor's Ubuntu image though which came on the laptop.

Later, I decided to have a dual boot configuration so I installed Ubuntu using the same vendor image I had backed up. Ubuntu installed succesfully but now I am unable to boot into Windows as it is not showing up as an entry in grub.

I tried boot-repair but it doesn't seem to work. Although I got the url http://paste.ubuntu.com/14429794/ It keeps repeating the message to 'unmount partitions' even in a live-usb system. I then tried bootscriptinfo which gave the output given below.

Also, I am sure that the whole windows partition is intact as I can see all the files in Ubuntu, it's just that I can't boot from it.

EDIT: I also tried the setroot method in the grub command line but it gave an error saying that the EFI path is not valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have already spent much time scouring forums and searching on Google.

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/MokManager.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so


sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda10: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda11: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.05 20140113
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 10154144 of /dev/sdb1 for 
                       its second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  
                       directory. No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /bootmgr 
                       /boot/bcd /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,026,048     1,107,967        81,920 -
/dev/sda3       1,107,968     7,399,423     6,291,456 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4       7,399,424     7,432,191        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda5       7,432,192   132,347,903   124,915,712 EFI System partition
/dev/sda6     132,347,904   133,269,503       921,600 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda7     133,269,504   238,127,103   104,857,600 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda8     238,127,104   868,321,279   630,194,176 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda9     868,321,280 1,393,657,855   525,336,576 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda10  1,393,657,856 1,918,994,431   525,336,576 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda11  1,918,994,432 1,953,523,711    34,529,280 Swap partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.2 GB, 16219373568 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1971 cylinders, total 31678464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *             63    31,678,463    31,678,401   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        008D-EE2D                              vfat       ESP
/dev/sda10       5430D21630D1FF44                       ntfs       New Volume
/dev/sda11       8b83b838-ad2b-4260-94b4-9480fd5b947d   swap       
/dev/sda2        0800-FF07                              vfat       DIAGS
/dev/sda3        A801-BD4C                              vfat       OS
/dev/sda4        7722aa47-a14c-4c99-a04e-8d5485dcbacc   ext4       
/dev/sda5        C6026F98026F8C6D                       ntfs       
/dev/sda6        BED4F2F6D4F2AFAF                       ntfs       
/dev/sda7        532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f   ext4       
/dev/sda8        16EC940EEC93E5F1                       ntfs       New Volume
/dev/sda9        9696C50A96C4EBB5                       ntfs       New Volume
/dev/sdb1        BE1A-5D9E                              vfat       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda10       /media/sachinkadyan7/New Volume1 fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw)
/dev/sda5        /media/sachinkadyan7/C6026F98026F8C6D fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6        /media/sachinkadyan7/BED4F2F6D4F2AFAF fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda9        /media/sachinkadyan7/New Volume fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1        /media/sachinkadyan7/BE1A-5D9E vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1001,gid=1001,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)


=========================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#########################################################
#                                                       #
# Dell Grub2 configuration file for ISO Images          #
# By: Mario Limonciello     #
#                                                       #
#########################################################

# First check for additional options on ISO image
if [ -s /factory/common.cfg ]; then
    source /factory/common.cfg
fi

#Post RTS deliverables
if [ -s /factory/post-rts-gfx.cfg ]; then
    source /factory/post-rts-gfx.cfg
fi
if [ -s /factory/post-rts-wlan.cfg ]; then
    source /factory/post-rts-wlan.cfg
fi

# If missing, load a nice basic default set
if [ -z "${options}" ]; then
    set options="boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt quiet splash --"
fi

# Setup theme
set timeout=5
set gfxmode=auto
insmod gfxterm
terminal_output gfxterm
loadfont /boot/grub/dejavu-sans-12.pf2
loadfont /boot/grub/dejavu-sans-bold-14.pf2
insmod gfxmenu
insmod png
set theme=/boot/grub/dell/theme.txt

# Search for the RP (which contains grubenv in /factory)
search --file --set=new_root /factory/grubenv
if [ -s ($new_root)/factory/grubenv ]; then
    set have_grubenv=true
    load_env -f ($new_root)/factory/grubenv
    if [ -n "${install_finished}" ]; then
        set timeout=-1
        menuentry "Install Complete, remove media and reboot." {
        chainloader +1
        }
    fi
    if [ "x${install_in_progress}" = "x1" ]; then
        set root=$new_root
        configfile ($new_root)/factory/grub.cfg
    fi
fi

#Default behavior
menuentry "Dell Recovery" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi $options
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Dell Recovery (safe graphics mode)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi $options ubiquity/force_failsafe_graphics=true
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=========================== sda7/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_IN
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f ro  quiet splash  radeon.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-38-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-38-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-38-generic-advanced-532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f ro  quiet splash  radeon.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-38-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-38-generic (safe mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-38-generic-recovery-532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-38-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda7/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=532c4cae-d2a5-49c8-8663-0af5e26cad1f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=008D-EE2D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda11 during installation
UUID=8b83b838-ad2b-4260-94b4-9480fd5b947d none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

====================== sda7/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf: =======================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf
##
## IMPORTANT WARNING
##
## The configuration of this file is generated automatically.
## Do not edit this file manually, use: extlinux-update


default l0
prompt 1
timeout 50

include themes/debian/theme.cfg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda7: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sda7: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


============== sda7: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 boot/extlinux/chain.c32            :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Comment: You are showing two ESP - efi system partitions. Boot flag with gpt must only be on one ESP per device/drive for most systems. The old BIOS boot flag would be on the Windows bootable partition which it looks like you have with your Windows. You have mixed UEFI & BIOS.

Comment: I agree with @oldfred: you have 2 EFI partitions on 2 separate disks: that will never work unless you change the bot in the UEFI system settings (aka "BIOS")

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

I experienced some similar issue with original Windows 10 setup and later installation of Ubuntu 14.04. I had a broken Ubuntu (due to some unknown Nvidia driver issue) and lost Windows boot loader.

Assumption being made:

1. Your Windows OS was installed using MBR mode (like mine).

If those were true, I would suggest you could "Create a Windows Recovery Disk" from another Windows 10 machine, which would provide you a minimal command line tool you could use. Then follow this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/950042/487346) to fix mbr (assuming your Windows OS lives in drive C):

```
bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr
```

Then reboot your computer. This will restore the Windows boot loader.

## More Information

I later learned about the relationship of MBR, BIOS mode, GPT, UEFI mode. Basically, MBR would pair with BIOS mode and GPT would pair with UEFI mode. ([Source](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Some_basics_of_MBR_v/s_GPT_and_BIOS_v/s_UEFI))

The boot loader mess was caused by the mismatching of Windows OS boot mode and Ubuntu boot mode. ([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI))